# How can I use this bat file properly for FTP?

Tags: batch-file, command

I currently have this in a .bat file of mine:

```
@echo off
echo user MyUserName> ftpcmd.dat
echo MyPassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat SERVERNAME.COM
del ftpcmd.dat
```

However, I'm very new with .bat files and I don't quite understand what each line is doing. So if somebody could explain this to me, it would be great. Also, how do I make it upload a file to a specific directory on the site? So mainly I'm asking what do I have to replace?

Comment: ftp clients can accept a list of commands to execute from a file. so this batch file simply dumps those commands into a file, then feeds the file into ftp. as for uploading to a specific dir... that you can do yourself... it'd just be some `cd` commands. teaching you how to ftp is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, however, what do I have to replace in order for it to upload a file to a specific directory on my site? I'm still very new to batch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a command to cd to the specific directory. Add

```
echo cd <path to directory> >> ftpcmd.dat
```

before

```
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
```

I would recommend reading through [this](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) to get an idea of how ftp works in general.